# Clojurescript + Node.js 0.12.7 issue (error "process.binding('evals') No such module: evals")

Tags: node.js, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to use Node.js + ClojureScript, and I found an article for it.

http://www.mase.io/code/clojure/node/2015/01/24/getting-started-with-clojurecript-and-node/

Following the instruction to find this error:

```
  process.binding('evals').NodeScript.runInThisContext.call(
          ^
Error: No such module: evals
    at Error (native)
```

The issue seems that I need to use old version of node:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojurescript/VneLWVpwe6o and https://github.com/kanso/kanso/issues/422

Mine is 0.12.7

```
pow> node --version
v0.12.7
```

In this case, I may need to use old version of node, but better yet, is there a way to bypass this issue? If none exists, how to use the old version of node.js in Mac OS X?

### Edit

Following https://github.com/creationix/nvm, I could install 0.10.32 version of node.js.

```
pow> nvm install 0.10.32
pow> node --version
v0.10.32
```

However, it gives me another error message:

```
pow> node entrypoint.js 
Hello world!

/Users/smcho/Desktop/clojurescript/pow/out/server/cljs/core.js:12133
var fixed_arity = f.cljs$lang$maxFixedArity;
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cljs$lang$maxFixedArity' of null
```

### Edit2

The error was because I forgot to update the core.cljs module to include `((set! *main-cli-fn* -main)`. It's mentioned in the original article, together with  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojurescript/DYpsiCmsyIs and https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#running-clojurescript-on-nodejs.

Comment: If you found a solution consider adding it as an answer and marking it as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [post](http://www.mase.io/code/clojure/node/2015/01/24/getting-started-with-clojurecript-and-node/), there are two ways to make it working, with Mac OSX, the two approaches require different version of node.js, and this is not clearly explained in the post.

#### The version that works with old node.js

_project.clj

```
(defproject pow "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    :description "FIXME: write this!"
    :url "http://example.com/FIXME"

    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2725"]]

    :node-dependencies [[source-map-support "0.2.8"]]

    :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]
                        [lein-npm "0.4.0"]]

    :source-paths ["src" "target/classes"]

    :clean-targets ["out/server/pow" "out/server/pow.js"]

    :cljsbuild {
        :builds [{:id "server"
                            :source-paths ["src/server"]
                            :compiler {
                                :main pow.core
                                :output-to "out/server/pow.js"
                                :output-dir "out/server"
                                :optimizations :none
                                :target :nodejs
                                :cache-analysis true
                                :source-map true}}
                         ]})
```

entry.js

```
// entrypoint.js
require("./out/server/goog/bootstrap/nodejs");
require("./out/server/pow");
require("./out/server/pow/core");
```

Run the script that executes the old node.js

```
#!/bin/bash
lein new mies pow
cd pow
cp ../_project.clj project.clj

mkdir src/server
mv src/pow src/server/

lein cljsbuild once
cp ../entrypoint.js .

/Users/smcho/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/node entrypoint.js
```

#### The version that works with new node.js

Modify the _project.clj

```
:optimizations :simple <-
:source-map "out/server/pow.js.map" <-
```

#### Run first part of runme.sh

```
lein new mies pow
cd pow
cp ../_project.clj project.clj

mkdir src/server
mv src/pow src/server/
```

MOdify core.clj

```
(ns pow.core
    (:require
                        [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]))

(enable-console-print!)

(defn -main []
    (println "Hello world!"))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

Then the second part of shell script

```
cd pow
lein cljsbuild once
node out/server/pow.js
```

### One more note

I wanted to use ClojureScript/Node.js in order to test clojureScript code without using web browsers. I found [LightTable](http://lighttable.com), and 
[a good tutorial about it](https://github.com/swannodette/lt-cljs-tutorial/blob/master/lt-cljs-tutorial.cljs). All I need to is open the LightTable, connect to LightTable UI as an output, then execute the script. So, I have much less reason to use ClojureScript/Node.js as of now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with two steps:

1) Declaring a `main` function

```
(ns testproj.core
  (:require
            [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]))

(enable-console-print!)

(defn -main []
  (println "Hello world!"))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

2) Setting `optimizations: simple` in my `project.clj`, as noted at the very bottom of [this blog post](http://www.mase.io/code/clojure/node/2015/01/24/getting-started-with-clojurecript-and-node/). For reasons unknown to me, `optimizations: none` breaks things.